# Convert react component to html

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, html2canvas, html-to-pdf

I have a react component containing a map (using [react-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet)).
I am trying to take a screenshot of the map 
(using [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas)) 
on the client side, convert it to HTML and then send it to my NodeJS server for creating a PDF (using [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)).
The problem is that the map loads its tiles from external URLs so when I try to take a screenshot I get a blank background.

Here is the component I want to take screenshot of:
[React map component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnPN8.png)

Here is the result in PDF:
[screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJhfT.png)

The code I've used:
on the client side:

```
// mapComponent is a div containing the component of the map.
let input = document.getElementById('mapComponent');
html2canvas(input)
    .then((canvas) => {
        let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        sendAjaxRequest(imgData);
    });
```

on the server:

```
let html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div>' +
    '<img src="' + imgData + '">' +
    '</div></body></html>';

let options = {
        format: 'A4',
        orientation: 'portrait'
    };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./file.pdf', (err, res) => {
    });
```

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: do the screenshot after the map has been loaded, [here's some infos](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/HEAD/docs/How%20it%20works.md) about `react-leaflet` lifecycle

Comment: @FeMachine 
Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't seem to work.  I have separated the screenshot to happen when the component is loaded completely but ended up with same result - a blank background.

Comment: did you check all the disclaimers from the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas)? maybe there's something you shouldn't do.. for example using sources from an external domain